# jquery on both div firing one after another

Tags: jquery

Im trying something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.popup').addClass('hide');
        return false;
    })

    $('.close1').click(function () {
        $('.popup_2').addClass('hide');
        return false;
    })
});
```

so hide is added to popup and popup_2

```
<div class="popup hide" style="display: block;">


<div class="popup_2 hide" style="display: block;">
```

when this hide class is added

```
<div id="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>
```

i want this overlay to go display:none..

logic

```
if(.popup.hide)&&(.popup_2.hide)==true
{
    // overlay should go display:none
}
```

kindly fix this issue

Comment: use `hasClass` jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given
>   class.

```
if($('.popup').hasClass('hide') && $('.popup_2').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('#overlay').hide();
}
```

Also, note that `<div>` is `display: block` by default. You don't need to set that style for it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use `hasClass` jquery :

```
 if($(".popup").hasClass('hide') && $(".popup_2").hasClass('hide') )
{
    $("#overlay").addClass('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.popup').addClass('hide');
        if($('.popup_2').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }

        return false;
    })

    $('.close1').click(function () {
        $('.popup_2').addClass('hide');
        if($('.popup').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

This will hide `overlay` when both popup will be hidden.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @TekexploreThiyagu accept the answer if helped, so it can be removed from unanswered question's list :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    function hide_overlay() {
        if ($('.popup').hasClass('hide') && $('.popup_2').hasClass('hide')) { //check condition here 
            $('#overlay').hide(); //hide when condition is true
        }
    }
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.popup').addClass('hide');
        hide_overlay(); //call function 
        return false;
    })

    $('.close1').click(function () {
        $('.popup_2').addClass('hide');
        hide_overlay();//call function 
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.close').click(function(){

    $('.popup').addClass('hide');  
    if( $('.popup_2').hasClass('hide') ){
      $('#overlay').hide();
    }
    return false;

})

$('.close1').click(function(){

    $('.popup_2').addClass('hide'); 
    if( $('.popup').hasClass('hide') ){
      $('#overlay').hide();
    }
    return false;

})
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/W42zv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!$('.popup').is(":visible") && !$('.popup_2').is(":visible")) {
    $('#overlay').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`if(!$('.popup').is(":visible") && !$('.popup_2').is(":visible")) {
    $('#overlay').hide();
}`